# Printing a triangle of characters in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I am developing this exercise:

> write the assembler program that, given a character as input, outputs a triangle of size 5 x 5 of the character itself.

I have a problem because when I go to input a character, the characters do not form a triangle, but other characters are printed.

My input:

> f

My output:

[image]

Desired output:

```
f
ff
fff
ffff
fffff
```

My code:

```
Title PROVA
;programma per la prova dell’ambiente Turbo Assembler 

DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100 
.DATA 
; se ci sono qui vanno dichiarate le vriabili

.CODE
  MOV AX, @data  ;(obbligatorie) inizializzano il DS      
  MOV DS, AX 
  
  MOV AX, 00
  MOV BX, 00
  MOV CX, 00
  MOV DX, 00

  mov ah,01h ;input va a mettere l'input in AL ;n
  int 21h
  MOV BL, AL ;n
  MOV CL, BL ;n
  
  MOV CH, 0H
  
  ciclo:
  CMP CH, 5H
  JE fine

  inc CH

  MOV DL, BL
  mov ah, 02h  ;stampa il contenuto di dl
  int 21h

  mov DL, 10D
  int 21h
  mov DL, 13D
  int 21h
  
  ;BL
  ADD BL, CL 
  
  JMP ciclo

  fine:
  MOV AL, 00H  ;(obbligatorie) ritornano il controllo al sistema operativo      
  MOV AH, 4CH 
  INT 21H 
 
END
```

Comment: I only see one loop in your code. For printing that shape I would've expected two loops, i.e. something like `for (row = 0; row < 5; row++) { for (col = 0; col <= row; col++) { printf(character); } }`

Comment: You keep the *character to print* in BL (and CL) but you are adding CL to BL after each *new line*, that's wrong. In order to display a character 1..5 times you have to repeat `int 21h` 1..5 times.  Use TurboDebugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vitsoft pointed out, the char changed because you add `CL` to `BL`.
To make a triangle you need to use another loop, as Michael said.
Below is the part to change:

```
  MOV   AH, 01h  ; input va a mettere l'input in AL ;n
  INT   21H
  MOV   BL, AL   ; n
  
  MOV   CH, 0H
ciclo:
  CMP   CH, 5H
  JE    fine
  INC   CH
  
  MOV   DL, 10D
  INT   21H
  MOV   DL, 13D
  INT   21H
  
  MOV   CL, CH
  MOV   AH, 02H  ; stampa il contenuto di dl
  MOV   DL, BL
innerLoop:
  INT   21H
  DEC   CL
  JNE   innerLoop

  JMP ciclo

fine:
```

Comment: Your program fails because the `MOV AH, 02H` instruction is not at the correct place!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ADD BL, CL 
> JMP ciclo
> ```

You seem to expect that this addition will double the number of characters. That is not the case! With BL and CL both holding your inputted "f" character, this instruction will just double the ASCII code for that particular character. And the DOS.PrintCharacter function 02h will only ever print a single character, so you need to repeat that operation in a loop.

> ```
> MOV AX, @data  ;(obbligatorie) inizializzano il DS      
> MOV DS, AX
> ```

If your program does not use items from the .DATA sections then setting up the DS segment register can be safely omitted.

> ```
> MOV AX, 00
> MOV BX, 00
> MOV CX, 00
> MOV DX, 00
> ```

This code is correct, but it is almost never needed to zero all your registers at program start. This program being a perfect example...

> ```
> MOV AL, 00H  ;(obbligatorie) ritornano il controllo al sistema operativo      
> MOV AH, 4CH 
> INT 21H
> ```

Again, this code is correct, but it is definitely not better to load AL and AH separately, when you can write `mov ax, 4C00h`.

This is your improved program:

```
Title PROVA
;programma per la prova dell’ambiente Turbo Assembler 

DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100 
.DATA 
; se ci sono qui vanno dichiarate le vriabili

.CODE
  mov  ah, 01h          ; DOS.GetKeyboardCharacter
  int  21h              ; -> AL
  mov  bl, al
  mov  ah, 02h          ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  mov  bp, 1            ; BP is number of characters on current line
OuterLoop:
  mov  cx, bp           ; Setup count in CX for the inner loop that follows
  mov  dl, bl           ; BL is the inputted character
InnerLoop:
  int  21h              ; -> AL == DL (BL)
  loop InnerLoop
  mov  dl, 13           ; Carriage return
  int  21h              ; -> AL == DL (13)
  mov  dl, 10           ; Linefeed
  int  21h              ; -> AL == DL (10)
  inc  bp
  cmp  bp, 6
  jb   OuterLoop

  mov  ax, 4C00h        ; DOS.TerminateWithReturncode
  int  21h
END
```

Below is my version that builds the entire output in a buffer memory and then prints it all at once with a single invokation of the DOS.PrintString function 09h.
It is perhaps not the most obvious way to solve this particular, extremely simple task, but at least:

- it justifies setting up DS
- it runs much faster due to a single API call to output

```
Title PROVA
;programma per la prova dell’ambiente Turbo Assembler 

DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100 
.DATA
Buffer db 100 dup (0)

.CODE
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  mov  ah, 01h          ; DOS.GetKeyboardCharacter
  int  21h              ; -> AL
  mov  dx, OFFSET Buffer
  mov  di, dx
  xor  cx, cx           ; CX is number of characters on current line
OuterLoop:
  inc  cx               ; -> CX=[1,5]
  mov  bx, cx
  mov  word ptr [di+bx], 0A0Dh ; Carriage return and linefeed together
InnerLoop:
  dec  bx               ; (*)
  mov  [di+bx], al      ; AL is the inputted character
  jnz  InnerLoop        ; (*) Acts on the flags defined by `DEC BX`
  add  di, cx
  add  di, 2
  cmp  cx, 5
  jb   OuterLoop
  mov  byte ptr [di], "$"
  mov  ah, 09h          ; DOS.PrintString
  int  21h              ; -> AL == "$"

  mov  ax, 4C00h        ; DOS.TerminateWithReturncode
  int  21h
END
```

Comment: `int 21h` / `ah=02` leaves AL=character output (http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02), so you'll need to stash the input char somewhere else, like `bl`, and use `si` or `di` for the loop counter in the nested-loop version.  The buffer-fill version looks good.  For *large* counts there might be a gain from `rep stosb`, although startup overhead makes it worse than a loop for small `n`.  (Ice Lake and later has fast-short-rep-movs, but that may not affect short stos vs. the usual microcode.  Some even later CPUs have fast-short-rep-scas/cmps, apparently, but maybe still not STOS?)

Comment: @PeterCordes Nice catch! I fixed the answer and this time also made a note about AL in my printed DOS functions guide.

Comment: Probably the most efficient way to build the string, at least on modern CPUs, is `memset` (`rep stosb` or `rep stosw`) to fill a buffer with `f` characters, then overwrite some with newlines at increasing strides.  Probably also on original 8088, since running 5 bytes of code for every byte, including a non-simple addressing mode and taken branch, is even more costly than 8088's 9+14n cycles for `rep stosw`, by enough to pay for the cost of extra stores.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way

```
org 100h
MOV AH, 2 
MOV BX, 0 

row:   
 INC BX
 MOV CX,BX 
    
    col:
    MOV DL, 102  

    int 21h
    loop col
    
MOV DL ,010 
INT 21h 
MOV DL, 13

INT 21h

CMP BL, 5
JE break

JMP row   
   
break:
 ret

ret
```

Comment: This is a 'code-only' answer! Why not add some explanations about why the OP was wrong and why your solution solves the issue? Some tail-comments in the code would have been nicer. Also, what about the double `ret` in the end, and that ugly `je break` instead of the normal `jne row`.

Comment: `MOV DL ,010` is an unclear way to write `mov dl, '\n'` (if MASM supports that) or `mov dl, 10`, the ASCII code for newline.  The leading zero is just confusing, especially since you don't use it on the carriage return `13` just after.  Also, the standard DOS line ending is CR LF (13, 10 in that order), so you have it backwards in case the user redirected output to a file.