# How to perform Data Movement and Arithmetic Instructions using TASM?

Tags: assembly, sum, x86-16, difference, tasm

We're currently in Assembly Programming and we were tasked to perform Basic Data Movement and Arithmetic Instructions using TASM. In this activity we should create a program that achieves these conditions:

a. Input must be single digit integer
b. Sum of two inputs must be less than 10
c. Difference of two inputs must be less than 10 but greater than 0.
d. Must ask for  command after input two or before displaying answers

An example output of this would be:

> ```
> Enter first integer: 7  
> Enter second integer: 2_  
> Sum: 9  
> Difference: 5
> ```

We tried this code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
msg1 db 'Enter first integer: $'
msg2 db 'Enter second integer: $'
msg3 db 'Sum: $'
msg4 db 'Difference: $'
newline db 0dh, 0ah, '$'
max_sum equ 10
max_diff equ 10

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; ask for first input
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, msg1
    int 21h

    ; read first input
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    sub al, 30h   
    mov bl, al    ; save first input in BL

    ; ask for second input
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, msg2
    int 21h

    ; read second input
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    sub al, 30h   
    mov cl, al    ; save second input in CL

    ; calculate sum
    add bl, cl
    cmp bl, max_sum
    jae error     ; if sum>10

    ; calculate difference
    mov al, bl
    sub al, cl
    cmp al, max_diff
    jae error     ; if diff > || < 10

    ; display sum
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, msg3
    int 21h
    mov dl, bl
    add dl, 30h  
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    ; display difference
mov ah, 9
lea dx, newline
int 21h
mov ah, 9
lea dx, msg4
int 21h
mov dl, al
add dl, 30h   
mov ah, 2
int 21h

; ask for <ENTER> command
mov ah, 9
lea dx, newline
int 21h

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

error:
    ; display error message
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, newline
    int 21h
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, msg1
    int 21h
    jmp main     ; repeat input process

main endp

end main
```

After running it, it works fine but the problem is the output comes out wrong, for example in the difference. Can you guys somehow teach us how to fix this? We are all beginners in this area and this was given to us without us having prior knowledge.

Comment: **Homework?** Mmmm...? Just askin' ...

Comment: @MikeRobinson: Questions *about* homework [are allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), as long as they meet all the other requirements for being on-topic.  This one is better than most, having a legit attempt, not just the teacher's framework with nothing added to "your code goes here", or a copy/paste of someone else's semi-related code that they hope will trick people into answering their homework for them.  The code is a bit long for an [mcve], but that's fairly normal for [assembly] questions.

Comment: The [mcve] is missing one important thing: you haven't shown what wrong output you actually get.  It's also missing any [debugging details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/), like what values you see in registers when single-stepping.  After `add bl, cl`, you've replaced one input with the sum.  So your next block is just subtracting that again . This should be clear if you look at register values while you single-step.  Compute stuff in `al` (or `dl`) and don't overwrite your inputs unless you don't mind subtracting twice to undo the add.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Not a "homework" per se. it was given to us as some sort of practice for an upcoming lab. We were given a cheat sheet before hand but it was not explained to us how it works or what does it do. We made the code in the post by utilizing the cheat sheet given to us and searching the internet for examples that we may use as reference. and in all honesty we still barely have any idea how it works.  If it goes against the terms and conditions of StackOverflow I will gladly take it down.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ; calculate sum
> add bl, cl
> cmp bl, max_sum
> jae error     ; if sum>10
> ```

Because you need to use both BL and CL inputs twice, once for their sum and once for their difference, you cannot store the sum in the BL register. You could store the sum in a memory-based, named variable, store it in a free register like BH, or push it on the stack. For a quick fix, I choose BH:

```
; calculate sum
mov  bh, bl
add  bh, cl
cmp  bh, max_sum
jae  error     ; if sum is 10 or more
```

---

> ```
> ; calculate difference
> mov al, bl
> sub al, cl
> cmp al, max_diff
> jae error     ; if diff > || < 10
> ```

You cannot leave the difference in the AL register as the DOS functions that you will be using next (DOS.PrintChar function 02h and DOS.PrintString function 09h) will both destroy AL. It is kind of funny that I too made a similar mistake in [an answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65956941/printing-a-triangle-of-characters-in-assembly/76194493#76194493) a couple of days ago. Let's use CH for the difference.
Now, just comparing to MAX_DIFF and jumping away on AboveOrEqual will only partially obey to what the task requires! Differences greater than 9 and differences smaller than 0 will get rejected, but what about 0 itself (BL == CL) ?

```
; calculate difference
mov  ch, bl
sub  ch, cl
jle  error     ; if diff is 0 or less
cmp  ch, max_diff
jge  error     ; if diff is 10 or more
```

---

> ```
> ; ask for <ENTER> command
> mov ah, 9
> lea dx, newline
> int 21h
> mov ah, 4ch
> int 21h
> ```

This code does not do what the comment says. And anyway, the task requires you to wait for <kbd>ENTER</kbd> **before** displaying the results. This here is right before exiting the program.

---

> ```
> mov ah, 9
> lea dx, msg1
> int 21h
> jmp main     ; repeat input process
> ```

Message *msg1* risks getting repeated. Prior to jumping to *main*, you should not print that 1st message as it will be almost the first thing that *main* does.

---

### My re-write

This also includes suitable newlines so the output resembles what you've indicated.

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
msg1     db 'Enter first integer: $'
msg2     db 13, 10, 'Enter second integer: $'
msg3     db 13, 10, 'Sum: $'
msg4     db 13, 10, 'Difference: $'
newline  db 13, 10, '$'
max_sum  equ 10
max_diff equ 10

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; ask for first input
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, msg1
    int 21h

    ; read first input
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    sub al, 30h   
    mov bl, al    ; save first input in BL

    ; ask for second input
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, msg2
    int 21h

    ; read second input
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    sub al, 30h   
    mov cl, al    ; save second input in CL

    ; calculate sum in BH
    mov  bh, bl
    add  bh, cl
    cmp  bh, max_sum
    jae  error     ; if sum is 10 or more

    ; calculate difference in CH
    mov  ch, bl
    sub  ch, cl
    jle  error     ; if diff is 0 or less
    cmp  ch, max_diff
    jge  error     ; if diff is 10 or more

    ***************************************
    HERE YOU NEED TO WAIT FOR THE ENTER KEY
    ***************************************

    ; display sum
    mov  ah, 9
    lea  dx, msg3
    int  21h
    mov  dl, bh        ; BH is sum
    add  dl, 30h  
    mov  ah, 2
    int  21h

    ; display difference
    mov  ah, 9
    lea  dx, msg4
    int  21h
    mov  dl, ch        ; CH is difference
    add  dl, 30h
    mov  ah, 2
    int 21h

    mov  ax, 4C00h
    int  21h

error:
    ; display error message
    mov  ah, 9
    lea  dx, newline
    int  21h
    jmp  main     ; repeat input process

main endp

end main
```

Comment: The other option, if you didn't have CH and BH available, would be to re-compute the sum and difference, in AL each time, first for the checks, then again after printing the text messages.  That barely takes more instructions, and partly pays for some of the code-size code since `cmp al, imm8` is only 2 bytes instead of 3.  (Speaking of which, `mov dl, 30h` / `add dl, bh` is shorter, and takes the mov off the critical path.  But that part of the OP's code didn't need to change.)

Comment: Another fun optimization for recomputing the sum plus `'0'` is `lea dx, [bx + '0']` / `add dl, cl` to copy-and-add.  That's how I might write it, but making minimal changes to the OP's version is probably easier for them to follow.

Comment: I see, thanks for the detailed explanation @PeterCordes. Ill be using your answer as a review. And to be completely frank I am still having a hard time understanding how each commands work (MOV, INT, LEA, etc.) and what does AX, BL, 21H, etc means. It's hard to learn when you were just given a cheat sheet but did not explain how each command works.  But nonetheless thank you!

Comment: If you can't spare a register, you could get sum and difference with `sub al, bl / add bl, bl / add bl, al`.

Answer (score 1):

Before msg3 al shows correct value, after msg3 al is changed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGk4u.png)

♠ = 6

Here is modified code ;)

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
   msg1 db 'Enter first integer: $'
   msg2 db 'Enter second integer: $'
   msg3 db 'Sum: $'
   msg4 db 'Difference: $'
   msg5 db '*** Error: Sum >= 10. Hint: Int1 + Int2 < 10 $'
   msg6 db '*** Error: Difference = 0. Hint: Int1 != Int2 $'
   newline db 0dh, 0ah, '$'
   max_sum equ 10
   ;max_diff equ 0

.code       
   main proc
   mov ax, @data
   mov ds, ax

   ; ask for first input
   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, msg1
   int 21h

   ; read first input
   mov ah, 1
   int 21h
   sub al, 30h   
   mov bl, al    ; save first input in BL

   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, newline
   int 21h

   ; ask for second input
   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, msg2
   int 21h

   ; read second input
   mov ah, 1
   int 21h
   sub al, 30h   
   mov cl, al    ; save second input in CL

   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, newline
   int 21h

   ; calculate sum
   push bx
   add bl, cl
   cmp bl, max_sum 
   jae error     ; if sum>10
   ; display sum
   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, msg3
   int 21h 
   mov dl, bl
   add dl, 30h  
   mov ah, 2
   int 21h

   pop bx

   ;calculate difference
   cmp bl,cl
   jz DiffIsZero
   ja positive_number
   jb negative_number

   positive_number:    
      mov al, bl      
      sub al, cl 
      jmp ShowDiff
 
   negative_number:    
      mov al, cl      
      sub al, bl  
      jmp ShowDiff

   ShowDiff:

   ; display difference
   push ax
   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, newline
   int 21h

   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, msg4
   int 21h
   pop ax

   mov dl, al
   add dl, 30h   
   mov ah, 2
   int 21h

  ; ask for <ENTER> command
   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, newline
   int 21h

   mov ah,8h     ; wait for key 
   int 21h

   mov ah, 4ch
   int 21h

  error:
     pop bx
     ; display error message sum >= 10
     mov ah, 9
     lea dx, newline
     int 21h

     mov ah, 9
     lea dx, msg5
     int 21h

     mov ah, 9
     lea dx, newline
     int 21h
     mov ah, 9
     lea dx, newline
     int 21h
     jmp main     ; repeat input process

 DiffIsZero:
   ; display error message, difference = 0
   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, newline
   int 21h

   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, newline
   int 21h
   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, msg6
   int 21h

   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, newline
   int 21h
   mov ah, 9
   lea dx, newline
   int 21h
   jmp main     

main endp

end main
```

Comment: Yup, that's a problem; this answer is pretty minimal in explaining why or how to fix it, though.  DOS output functions affect AL.  http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09 documents that `int 21h` / `ah=09h` leaves AL=24h (the terminating `'$'`).  Compute something to be output in a different register, and/or *after* outputting the strings.  e.g. output a string, then compute something in DL.

Comment: An overflow on the *sum* will leave the stack unbalanced due to `push bx`. The verification on the *difference* is completely wrong.

Comment: 1. If I understand correctly I forgot to add POP BX in error section in case program makes a jump on istruction JAE ERROR ? 2. I changed code in difference part. I don't know if this is better?

Comment: @0Signal Your corrections look fine to me. Definitely worth my upvote. I guess there's some ambiguity in how the task's requirements were laid out: "Difference of two inputs must be less than 10 but greater than 0." *You* have interpreted this as "the absolute difference" whereas *I* have considered "the value of 1st input minus 2nd input".